# Having an issue connecting my Angular Controller to my View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, controller

I'm trying to connect a controller to my view and I keep getting this error:

> Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'TestAppCtrl' is not a function,
>   got undefined

I have this view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Resume Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- ExtraCSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/extra.css">    

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- External JS extras -->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <h3>Resume</h3>
        </div>

            <div ng-controller="TestAppCtrl" id="TestAppCtrl">
            {{data}}
            </div>   

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 span4"> 
                <h4>About</h4>
                <div>
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#technical" aria-controls="technical" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Technical</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#school" aria-controls="school" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">School</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#experience" aria-controls="experience" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Experience</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="technical">

                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="school">
                            .t..
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="experience">
                            .z..
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
                <h4>Contact Info</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>







    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this controller:
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.3
    var app;

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

console.log("hello world");

app.controller('TestAppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}]);
```

I know it's finding the correct controller because the console log prints. But the data in the controller isn't binding in the view it's just showing as {{data}} any suggestions would help a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ng-app twice

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app lang="en">
...
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
```

Angular will use the first one on the page, your initialization statement is referencing the 2nd ng-app

```
app = angular.module('app', []);
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that!